# Input sequence contained in an array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to implement this excercise but it doesn't work very well. It should tell me if the sequence in array B is contained in A. Any ideas? I have a problem getting it to work for every sequence.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 6
#define M 3

int contains(int v[], int n);

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int A[N], B[M];
    int i, j = 0, flag = 0, contained = 1;

    printf("Array A\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("Insert element: ");
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    }

    printf("Array B\n");
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        printf("Insert element: ");
        scanf("%d", &B[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (N - M + 1); i++)
    {
        flag = 0;

        if (A[i] == B[j])
        {
            flag = 1;
            j++;
        }

        if (flag == 0 && (i == N-M))
        {
            contained = 0;
            printf("The sequence B is not contained in A!\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    if (contained == 1)
    {
        printf("The sequence B is contained in A\n");
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a non match in the sequence, you never reset `j` so you start looking for the rest of the sequence starting to what ever value `j` was left at. Your program looks for the sequence `B` but doesn't require it to be contiguous.

You also don't check for when the sequence is completed so it for example `B` is at the start of `A` the `j` will keep incrementing and `B[j]` will overflow into unknown memory which is unlikely to match `A` so will give you an incorrect result. To fix this just check for when the whole of `B` is found and exit the loop.

Substituting the following will fix this:

```
if (j == M) break; // Break the loop when B sequence is found
if (flag == 0)
{
    j = 0;    // This was missing
    if (i == N-M)
    {
        contained = 0;
        printf("The sequence B is not contained in A!\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is not the right solution.  If I insert the sequence: 1 2 5 10 9 11 and Array B 1 2 5 the program doesnt' work

Comment: I just noticed that, fixing now

Answer (score 1):

For the third `for` loop when you're doing the check, you're (1) not actually checking every element of `B` against the corresponding element of `A` and (2) not checking the different start indices. What you probably meant to do is something like

```
for (i = 0; i < (N - M + 1); i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
        if (A[i + j] != B[j]) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (j == M) {
        printf("Found a match!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as your spinning through A if you find that an element of B does not match A then you need to set j back to 0

Answer (score 0):

For searching B in A you may want to do something like following:

```
for (i = 0; i < (N - M + 1) ; i++)
    if (A[i] == B[0])
    {  j=0;
       while (A[++i] == B[++j] && j<M);
       break;
    }

if (j == M)
{
    printf("The sequence B is contained in A\n");
}

else{
    printf("The sequence B is not contained in A\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < (N - M + 1); i++)
{
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < M; j++) 
    {
        if(B[j] != A[j + i])
            break;
    }
    /* sequence found */
    if(j == M)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

GCC has the memmem() extention function (which is basically strstr(), but does not rely on NUL-terminated strings)

```
if (memmem(A, N * sizeof *A, B, M * sizeof *B)) {
   printf("Found\n" );
} else {
   printf("Not Found\n" );
   }
```